# I shared a link on Twitter and Facebook - How many people followed it?

Tags: discussion, links, statistics

I shared a question link ( http://t.co/KvI45YO  ) on Twitter and Facebook because it is an interesting question and I'd like to help drive my friends and followers to this site.  Is there a way for me to see how many times the link was followed like I can see when I share a link with bit.ly?

Answer (score 2):

There is currently no way to get that kind of click-through data through Stack Exchange. But, actually, using http://bit.ly is a great way to get that data:

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I normally use bit.ly, but this time I used the "link thingy" @neilfein mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Did you share the link to the question from the little "link" thingy under the question's tags? If so, that link has your username embedded in it, and if enough people follow it, you'll get a badge. See this question:

[Publicist badge](https://bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121/publicist-badge)

And also this blog post:

[Announcer, Booster, and Publicist Badges](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/)